# Apple's iCloud SMTP Server For Old Devices Does Not Work

Tags: ipod-touch, icloud

I have set up my iPod Touch 1G to use the iCloud mail servers as per http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864. IMAP works, but SMTP, although it worked for the first ~24 hours, refuses to work, complaining that the username or password is incorrect. I tried manually using this SMTP server on my Mac (Lion 10.7.2) and it gives the same result. Is anyone able to send emails via smtp.mail.me.com or has anyone experienced this problem and has a fix for it?

EDIT: I have checked with a new iCloud account (set up on 4th Nov) and it works, so if anyone else has this issue it is a problem with your account. AppleCare, get ready!

Comment: I have been getting periodic password incorrect errors and am 100% certain it hasn't changed and is stored properly in my Lion mac's keychain. Are you sure it's not a capacity or account issue? I'm getting errors on smtp.mail.me.com on Lion for the last hour or two.

Comment: It's been like this constantly for the past 1.5 weeks for me :/ Plus I have not changed my password

Comment: Ouch - you might need to open a ticket with MobileMe to get your account looked at. They can get stuck...

Comment: I have called them up several times, and haven't got anywhere. Will try again tomorrow (I live in the UK)

Comment: I'm amazed at the breadth of international support for iCloud already - http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/ww/ - good luck!

Comment: Yes, I have experienced this; no, I don't have a fix for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it recently started working, so let's hope it stays that way!

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... I wasn't aware that it was possible to use this service on earlier iOS version & hardware models. The iCloud SMTP server (at least on iOS 5) uses an authentication token specifically from Apple.

Comment: -1 as Apple says it should work (in the link) and it works with a different account.

Comment: They actually don't specifically say it will work regardless of the platform or iOS version, if you want to focus on wording. The only other suggestion would be to use the other SMTP servers for iCloud (p01-smtp.mail.me.com, p02-smtp.mail.me.com, etc.)

Comment: But I have still proved that it is my account and not the server!

Comment: @jrtc27 I'm not sure I follow the last comment in relation to what I said.